# Macros vs functions

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Early steps with macros and looking for clarification.

```lisp
(defmacro nil! (x)      
  (list 'setf x nil))
```

Paul Graham writes on p169 of ANSI CL

> `nil!`, `ntimes` and `while` all have to be written as macros because all have to control the way in which their arguments are evaluated.

I looked at `nil!` and thought, wait a minute, I want to try writing that as a function. Turned out he's right, as expected, but looking to pin down why. If I do

```lisp
(defun nil!f (x)
  (setf x nil))

(setf a 9)
(nil!f a)
; a is still 9, not nil
```

Having forced myself into this, I note this is an odd use of a function, because I would not normally `setf` a parameter. If I was going to `setf` in a function it would more likely be a global, not a parameter.

If I have it correct, the parameter `x` creates a new lexical scope, which obscures the `a` which i set at the top level. Meaning we can pass in a value to a function, but not a variable.

Whereas with macros we can deal in variables.

Of course we can do this

```lisp
(defun nil!f-a ()
  (setf a nil))
```

but now we lost the ability to pass in a variable to this particular function so it's a stumped version of original.

Hence the exact thing a macro allows you to do here is...  ?

Second question, is this a true statement

> "In CL you cannot pass a variable into a function"

Here I yield...

Comment: Are you familiar with other programming languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defun nil!f (x)
  (setf x nil))
```

If you do that, you can only set the new local variable `x` to `nil`. In plain Common Lisp it is not possible that this has another effect.

```
(defmacro nil! (x)      
  (list 'setf x nil))

(nil! foo)
```

Above expression will be replaced before execution with

```
(setf foo nil)
```

We can check that:

```
CL-USER 110 > (macroexpand-1 '(nil! foo))
(SETF FOO NIL)
```

Thus, since it is before execution, you can do all kinds of source (!) manipulation then.

> "In CL you cannot pass a variable into a function"

That's true for lexical variables. Dynamically bound variables could be passed in as symbols.

Dynamically bound:

```
CL-USER 111 > (flet ((f (sym)
                       (symbol-value sym)))
                (let ((a 10))
                  (declare (special a))
                  (f 'a)))
10
```

Lexically bound:

```
CL-USER 112 > (flet ((f (sym)
                       (symbol-value sym)))
                (let ((a 10))
                  (f 'a)))

Error: The variable A is unbound.
```